# Insert to Mongodb and MySQL together - auto increment

Tags: mysql, mongodb, concurrency, nonblocking

In an operation I need to insert data into MySQL and Mongodb together using php, I want to use the same ID to refer to both. I am new to mongodb, and the usual way I do is just use auto increment in MySQL.

My questions are:

1. I have seen people suggesting that MySQL's auto increment would suffer from concurrency issue. Is Mongodb better for creating the ID ?(I am not using the self generated object ID I guess, so it would still be an ascending integer sequence)
2. If I am dealing with the insertion to the two DBs in one php page, would it matter if I do mongodb first or later?